# Magento2 Multistore - direrent products in each Store

Tags: magento2, multistore, products

I have one website "My Brand" only one centralized URL domain for my customers, multiple stores for (USA, Europe, and Latin America) and three views for each stores (Spanish, English, Portuguese)

I have 50 SKUs that i want to have all of the in my centralized product catalog in my Brand Web Site.

How to do to show some products in the USA Store, some others in Europe Store and some others in the Latin America stores. Is there any way to assign products to each store... like SKU A active in Store 1 and 2, and SKU B active in Store 3 only etc...?

I know you can manage diferent prices for the same SKU in each store, but i dont know if you would need an extension to be able to show specific SKUs in each store.

Thanks

JLM

Answer (score 0):

Products can be assigned to individual websites without the necessity of installing an extension.

**How to assign or unassign a single product to/from a website**

There is a **Product in Websites** section on the product page in the *Admin* area (*Catalog* > *Product* > select product and *edit*).

By ticking / unticking the boxes for the specific websites, the product can be assigned to / unassigned from them.

**How to assign or unassign multiple products to/from a website**

There is also a bulk editing option, in case you want to assign / unassign many products to a website:

1. Browse to *Catalog* > *Products*
2. Filter for the products you want to assign / unassign to a specific store
3. Select the products you want to assign / unassign (checkboxes)
4. Look for the dropdown field labelled "Actions" above the list of products. Click its arrow and select *Update attributes*.
5. The *Update Attribute* page appears. Select *Websites* in the tab-menu on the left hand side.
6. Tick boxes in the sections **Add Product To Websites** / **Remove Product From Websites** as required
7. Click on the *Save* button in the top right corner of the page

Comment: I mean i have a catalog for the web site and want to show some items in one STORE and others items in the other STORES...  so the question in how to show some products of the web site catalog in one store and some others in other store. Example.:  SKU1 will be only sold in store USA, while SKU2 in STORE Europe

Comment: I already know how to assign products to diferent web sites, my question is how to show some of them in one store and some of them in the other store (both stores bolong to the same web site)

Comment: Oh, my apologies. Are these different "stores" or maybe different "store views", then? (https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/multi-site/ms_over.html)

Comment: Does this answer maybe help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6790279/magento-different-products-in-the-different-store-views-under-the-same-store

Comment: 1 WEBSITE with 1 Product Catalog with 50 items. 3 STORES, each store i want to know if one of them could show 20 of the 50 items and the other one all of them (50) and the third store maybe 12 items of the 50. Then VIEWS i will have 2 views for each STORE (english and Spanish)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this product visibility, Edit the product then select store view then change the product visibility.

Answer (score 0):

Jose, based on this:

> I have one website "My Brand" only one centralized URL domain for my customers, multiple stores for (USA, Europe, and Latin America) and three views for each stores (Spanish, English, Portuguese)

I assume that structure of your Magento instance looks like this:

- Main_Website

  - US_Store

    - EN_Store_View
    - ES_Store_View
    - PT_Store_View
  - EU_Store

    - EN_Store_View
    - ES_Store_View
    - PT_Store_View
  - LA_Store

    - EN_Store_View
    - ES_Store_View
    - PT_Store_View

You have 50 SKUs - all assigned to Main_Website (in Product in Websites tab on product edit page)

What you need to do in order to have different catalog per store is to create 3 Root Categories - one per each Store.

Then you can create different category tree (or the same) under each Root Category and assign different products to different categories under each Root Category. This way you can manage different catalog per each Store.

Here is official documentation of Root Category for Magento 2 - https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/catalog/category-root.html

Additionally, in "multisite" setups you need to remember about planning your structure in relation to Payment Methods, Shipping Methods, Base Currency etc. as they require separate website if you want to configure them differently for different countries (they can't be different in scope of one website). Good explanation about differences between Magento website, store and store view can be found here -> http://qatribe.pl/differences-between-magento-website-store-and-store-view/